# Highest median score of a full innings in test cricket

Tags: cricket, records

Considering all the median scores of a full innings (All the 10 wickets fall), what is the highest among those, i.e, the greatest median run score from a full team of batsmen from a single innings? Which match did this happen and what was the result of this match?

I'm primarily interested in test cricket, but answers from first class cricket, one day or Twenty20 would be of interest too.

Comment: As per your other question, you need to say which type & standard of cricket you're talking about.

Comment: Yes - again I take your point - I was thinking international test cricket, but other types would also be interesting. I commented on the other question more about why I was interested.

Comment: OK, I suggest you edit to question to say test cricket. At the moment it's phrased in a way that would include under-9 cricket on the Isle of Wight, which is a wee bit too broad!

Answer (score 2):

Test: **61** by [West Indies 1st innings](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/12674/scorecard/535999/India-vs-West-Indies-3rd-Test-West-Indies-tour-of-India-2011-12)

ODI: **30** by [Sri Lanka](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/11852/scorecard/657637/Pakistan-vs-Sri-Lanka-1st-ODI-Sri-Lanka-tour-of-United-Arab-Emirates-2013-14)

T20I: **16** by [Pakistan](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/11215/scorecard/902649/England-vs-Pakistan-1st-T20I-England-tour-of-United-Arab-Emirates-2015-16)

First class: **73** by [Bengal 1st innings](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ARCHIVE/1950S/1951-52/IND_LOCAL/RANJI/BENG_ASSAM_RJI_24-26JAN1952.html) and [Rest of India 1st innings](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8470/game/465502/Mumbai-vs-Rest-of-India--Irani-Cup)

List A: **48** by [Northern Districts](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8880/scorecard/580795/Northern-Districts-vs-Central-Districts--The-Ford-Trophy)

T20: **18** by [Multan Tigers](http://www.pcb.com.pk/abnamro-twenty20-cup-200506/match/12904.html) and 
[Kent](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8053/scorecard/225319/Essex-vs-Kent--Twenty20-Cup-2006)